# Where to find/download lib rsvg for python on OSX

Tags: python, macos, librsvg, rsvg

I'm looking to use the python library rsvg for converting an SVG graphic to other formats (mainly PDF) and cannot seem to find the python-librsvg source to download and install on Mac OSX anywhere. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

I've finally found it. It's buried in a Macports package called `gnome-python-desktop`:

```
$ sudo port install gnome-python-desktop
```

Everything I can find suggests it is available nowhere else. Both [this](http://cairographics.org/pyrsvg/) and [this](http://www.karoltomala.com/blog/?p=551) page say it is wrapped up in GNOME Desktop and is not stand-alone. Same deal on Linux (in Ubuntu the name of the package is `python-gnome2-desktop`). There is a [package on GitHub](https://github.com/jmcb/python-rsvg-dependencies) that looks a bit more lightweight, but it is Windows-only.

I also discovered something else disturbing: this module [hasn't been updated since 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393675/rsvg-with-python-3-2-on-ubuntu). So if possible, it would be best to stay well away from it. :-/

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts has a version of it:  http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=librsvg

Comment: That's the Gnome library, not the python bindings to it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, the MacPorts portfile for librsvg has python27 as a dependency which I assumed was for the bindings.  Presumably you would still need to install the library in any case.